# Cyclic voltammetry graph of graphite electrode in NaOH

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, redox, reduction-potential, cyclic-voltammetry

I'm a student who is a beginner to cyclic voltammetry and university electrochemistry in general. For my lab experiment, I performed cyclic voltammetry on a graphite electrode in 1 M NaOH with Ag|AgCl reference electrode.

I was wondering why I got this kind of graph, instead of a leaf shape indicative of the formation of an electrochemical double layer. I tried searching but I can't find any source writing about such a simple setup.

I am hoping if anyone can explain the shape of this graph, and why I did not get a leaf shape CV graph.

[image: cyclic voltammetry graph of graphite electrode in 1M NaOH]

Comment: Did you clean the electrode? It seems something Is getting reduced, maybe some impurities?
Also, what is the diameter of the electrode you are using? and the scan rate, maybe use a faster one? If you are a beginner, I recommend you also read this [ARTICLE](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jchemed.7b00361) :